# Problems running Chrome through shortcut on Windows 8

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8-preview, shortcuts

all of a sudden, i can only run chrome as admin. it says the path to `chrome.exe` doesn't exist, but the file is there after i check.

update menu said i have windows updates installed last night, but when i look through all the updates i can't find anything that were installed last night.

when i right click on `chrome.exe` and `Pin to Start`, it doesn't pin it. But pin/unpin to Taskbar works.

even more strange, if i right click on `chrome.exe` and drag to desktop to create a shortcut, then double click on the shortcut, it works the first time. when double click again, it doesn't work anymore.

tried to re-install chrome but that didn't help either.

oh, double click on `chrome.exe` works every time but i like shortcut better.

all of above were done while logged in as administrator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same problem tonight.  I was able to narrow the issue down to a the latest Chrome update (21.0.1180.79).  This is not an issue with the previous version (21.0.1180.77).  Specific versions of Chrome are available from [filehippo.com](http://www.filehippo.com/download_google_chrome/)

First check this UAC setting:

1. Run secpol.msc
2. Navigate to Local Policies->Security Options
3. Find the policy named "User Account Control: Only elevate UIAccess applications that are installed in secure locations" and set this to "Disabled"

This may alleviate the problem.

Steps to replicate:

1. Uninstall Google Chrome
2. Run the 21.0.1180.75 installer
3. Run the 21.0.1180.77 installer
4. Run the 21.0.1180.79 installer

The shortcut should now break.

Steps to fix:

1. Uninstall Chrome with `21.0.1180.79_chrome_installer.exe --uninstall`
2. Reinstall Chrome with `21.0.1180.79_chrome_installer.exe`

Alternatively, install the [Chrome Browser for Business](http://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/business/browser/), which installs itself in Program Files, which is considered a "secure location".

Comment: I like your "User Account Control: Only elevate UIAccess applications that are installed in secure locations - and set it to Disabled" answer more.

Comment: Wasn't sure that was the real issue.  I couldn't replicate it.  I'll include some information about that.

Answer (score 0):

This problem appeared for me after a windows update was installed over night. I have searched and searched and I finally have it working, at least for now. The shortcuts stop working again for other users after a week and the workaround has to be done again. I posted the instructions here but another thing is that Chrome doesn't need to be ran as admin so I made sure to go to its folder (in Program Files x86) and deselect "run as admin" in the properties of chrome.exe

Here is the link:

https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/chrome/agGUrplBu-Y/Gr5Yp2K4gnUJ

Hope this proves helpful! :)